# Shapfile attribute data processing using ArcPy in IDLE

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, fields-attributes, idle, scatterplot

I am working on  shapefile data using ArcPy in IDLE environment. How can I access/read two attributes of a shapefile and create a scatter plot using ArcPy?

This is what I am getting:

[image: This is what I am getting]

This is what I need:

**[image: This is what I need]**

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
env.workspace = "C:/Users/zohaib pc/Documents/MS_second_semester/PYTHON_GIS/PYTHON_GIS/python final"
readd= "pm25.shp"
nparr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(readd,['AQI_yearly', 'PM25_yearl'])
plt.plot([nparr['PM25_yearl'],nparr['AQI_yearly']])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Read data into a pandas dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(readd, ['AQI_yearly', 'PM25_yearl']), columns=['AQI_yearly', 'PM25_yearl'])` then [plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html)

Comment: i am working on arcpy.  i need to create scatter plots for attribute table parameters using arcpy function that would only be possible when i am able to access attribute field data. pandas again is a whole new thing. is that be possible with arcpy?